# How do i know my device ScreenLock settings in Android

Tags: android, settings

How can i read the settings for my ScreenLock in Android ? Whether the scree lock is
None / Slide / Pattern / PIN/Password lock ?

I can find only one API to know whether it is pattern lock or not .

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a similar question asked here. Use KeyguardManager to check if the device is locked.

KeyguardManager kgMgr = 
    (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
boolean showing = kgMgr.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();

Comment: this will only tell the current state of the screen . But i want to read the settings and write the logic accordignly ..